# Is there a way to make nice (process priority) values survive a reboot?

Tags: raspbian, daemon, sysvinit, nice

I've been working on setting my Pi up as a seedbox, which I have no finally got working. My issue is that I also use this Pi as a mumble server and NAS for my media in home. I'm quite comfortable with using renice to prioritise mumble, samba, deluge-web and deluge respectively, but at the moment I have to do this manually if I ever restart the server. Is there a way to automate this, or assign a niceness permanently?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: I added the `sysvinit` tag presuming that's what's starting mumble, samba etc., although I don't *think* it has a mechanism to do this.

Answer (score 4):

The sysvinit init.d scripts often use `start-stop-daemon`. 
You can modify them and add [`-N` options](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/en/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html) to change the nice level of the daemons.

Beside this, you can write your own script that renices the processes and call it in `/etc/init.d/rc.local`.

There are also auto nice daemons (like [AND](http://and.sourceforge.net/)) which can do this task automatically.

Comment: Modifying the init scripts is easy enough (just stick `nice` appropriately into the `start` section) -- just beware that (presumably) they *might* occasionally be replaced on upgrade.

Comment: Excellent, i'll have a look into those! Thanks for the help.